# Запятые в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение: 
Кроме собственного производства созданы развитая логистика и маркетинг, что вместе с современными информационными технологиями и интернетом позволяет обеспечить быстрое и качественное выполнение практически любого заказа и любой номенклатуры.

И есть два вопроса. Во-первых, оборот с предлогом "кроме". Насколько я поняла - обособление факультативно и данном случае не требуется... И во-вторых, надо ли выделять запятыми оборот "вместе с современными технологиями и интернетом"?
Буду признательна за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемый вариант:

"Кроме собственного производства, созданы развитая логистика и маркетинг, что вместе с современными информационными технологиями и интернетом позволяет обеспечить быстрое и качественное выполнение практически любого заказа и любой номенклатуры".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Практически все ограничительно-расширительные члены предложения с наречными предлогами  КРОМЕ, ПОМИМО, ИСКЛЮЧАЯ, ВКЛЮЧАЯ, ЗА ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕМ, СВЕРХ, НАРЯДУ, выделяются запятыми, кроме оборотов со словом ВМЕСТО, для которого характерны три  варианта: а) всегда обособляется; б) не обособляется; в) авторский вариант.

2) Оборот с предлогом ВМЕСТЕ С ТЕМ обычно не обособляется, например:

"Сидящие за столиками стали приподниматься и всматриваться и увидели, что вместе с огонёчком шествует к ресторану белое привидение (М. А. Булгаков).

"Больше того: есть опасность, что вместе с увеличением числа муниципальных образований возрастет и число чиновников.

Comment: Спасибо. Но вот я у Розенталя нашла пример, где не обособляется: Обычно не обособляется оборот с предлогом кроме со значением включения в предложениях типа: Кроме зарплаты они получают премиальные. В остальных примерах, правда, обороты с кроме обособляются. А здесь не похожий вариант?

Comment: Пример, где не обособляется оборот со значением включения: "Необходимо сушить на зиму укроп, который кроме полезных для организма свойств придаёт вкус кушаньям (Елена Молоховец, 1875-1900). Этот оборот можно заменить выражением "дополнительно к", который не обособляется. Но, как Серж нам подробно объяснил, в современной орфографии значение оборота (включение или выключение) не учитывается

Answer (score 1):

Примечание 1. Оборот с предлогом кроме имеет два значения: а) одно совпадает со значением слов за исключением, т. е. имеет значение исключения из ряда подобных предметов: На всех берегах залива на протяжении сотен верст мною не было встречено ни одного человека, и, кроме горчайшей полыни и сухого бурьяна, я не сорвал ни одной травинки (Пауст.); Вершинин отправил луговиков в институт, всех, кроме Свиридовой, — ее он включил в высокогорный отряд (Зал.); б) другое — это обозначение включения в ряд подобных предметов: У Бунина, кроме блестящих, совершенно классических рассказов, есть необычайные по чистоте рисунки (Пауст.); Я слышал, кроме гудения мотора, еще несколько звуков (Пауст.).

В настоящее время различия в значениях оборотов со словом кроме не сказываются на пунктуации: и в том и в другом случае предусмотрено выделение запятыми. Однако в прошлом обороты со значением включения знаками препинания не выделялись. Ср.: Кроме учителей на собрание пришли и ученики. — Кроме учителей, на собрание никто не пришел. (Полный академический справочник)